# Smart pointers and cyclic/noncyclic lists

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

First I use only shared_ptr for both list:

```
struct Elem {
    string cargo;
    shared_ptr<Elem> next;
    Elem(string cargo) {
        this->cargo = cargo;
    }
    ~Elem() {
        cout << "delete Elem " << cargo << endl;
    }
};

static shared_ptr<Elem> make3nonCyclic() {
    shared_ptr<Elem> A(new Elem("A"));
    shared_ptr<Elem> B(new Elem("B"));
    shared_ptr<Elem> C(new Elem("C"));
    A->next = B;
    B->next = C;
    return A;
}


static shared_ptr<Elem> make3cyclic() {
    shared_ptr<Elem> A(new Elem("A"));
    shared_ptr<Elem> B(new Elem("B"));
    shared_ptr<Elem> C(new Elem("C"));
    A->next = B;
    B->next = C;
    C->next = A;
    return A;
}

static void test2() {
    //non cyclic list of three
    shared_ptr<Elem> head = make3nonCyclic();
    head = head->next;
    cout << "elem A should be deleeted" << endl;
}

static void test3() {
    //cyclic list of three
    shared_ptr<Elem> head = make3cyclic();
    head = head->next;
    cout << "elem A should not be deleeted" << endl;
}
```

For noncyclic list works fine, (except that call recursion instead of tail iteration)
For cyclic, does not release.
I tried

- change field next to weak_ptr: releases all too early
- change return type in make3cyclic and head in test3 to weak_ptr: does not release.
  How do this samples? And more complicated:

```
struct Node {
    shared_ptr<Node> parent;
    Node(shared_ptr<Node> parent) {
        this->parent = parent;
        if (parent!=nullptr)
            depth = parent->depth+1;
    }
    int depth = 0;
    vector<shared_ptr<Node>> children;
    shared_ptr<Node> addChild(shared_ptr<Node> parent) {
        shared_ptr<Node> child(new Node(parent));
        children.push_back(child);
        return child;
    }
};
```

In "How does weak_ptr work?" I can see:
"The pointee is deleted when the "use count" reaches zero.

The "counter" helper object is deleted when the "weak count" reaches zero (which means the "use count" must also be zero, see above)."

I thought that pointee and counter objects are closely related and pointee can't exists if counter objects is freed.

Comment: The first lesson when it comes to lists is that it becomes much simpler to handle if you separate *lists* from *nodes*.

Comment: As for your problem, you never sever all connections to the `A` node, you still have a link to it (from the `C` node). If you want to remove a node from a list you need to update *all* pointers to it (`C` should point to `B`).

Comment: Yes, but if A,B,C and head is out of scope, whole cyclic list should be freed. Link from C to A should be weak? but field C.next is the same type as A.next and B.next.

Comment: `whole cyclic list should be freed` If it's a loop, nothing will be freed, cause every shared pointer still has one user, the previous element in the loop. You have to break the loop.

Comment: By setting head.next = nullptr ?

Answer (score 0):

The objects are not releasing in case of list created by `make3cyclic()` function i.e. cyclic list, because object reference counts of none of the objects reaches 0.

Reference count of each object in `make3cyclic()` function and before the line `head = head->next;` in function `test3()` is 2 as explained in below image:
[image: Reference count of each object is 2]

After the line `head = head->next;` in function `test3()` the reference count of object `B` and `C` is 2 but for object `A` it is still 1 ( and not 0 which you would have thinking ) as explained in below image:  [image: Reference count of object A is still 1]

If you want to free the memory of then you should add a line `head->next->next = nullptr;` after the line `head = head->next;` as in bellow. [See it working here](https://ideone.com/GlsS4T):

```
static void test3()
{
    //cyclic list of three
    shared_ptr<Elem> head = make3cyclic();
    head = head->next;
    head->next->next = nullptr;
    cout << "elem A should be deleted now" << endl;
}
```

For your complex scenerio, you can do somthing following (***Note:*** I have added `_key` member just to show a meaningful log of object destrunction). [See in action here](https://ideone.com/AGJae5):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Node 
{
    weak_ptr<Node> parent;
    char _key;
    int depth = 0;
    vector<shared_ptr<Node>> children;
    
    Node(shared_ptr<Node> parent, const char key) : _key(key)
    {
        this->parent = parent;
        if ( parent )
            depth = parent->depth+1;
    }
    
    ~Node() 
    {
        cout << "delete Node [" << _key << " | " << depth << "]\n";
    }
    
    shared_ptr<Node> addChild( shared_ptr<Node> parent, const char key )
    {
        shared_ptr<Node> child = make_shared<Node>(parent, key);
        children.push_back(child);
        return child;
    }
};


int main() 
{
    auto p = weak_ptr<Node>();
    shared_ptr<Node> root = make_shared<Node>( nullptr, 'A' );
    auto b = root->addChild( root, 'B' );
    root->addChild( root, 'C' );
    root->addChild( root, 'D' );
    b->addChild( b, 'E' );
    auto f = b->addChild( b, 'F' );
    b->addChild( b, 'G' );
    f->addChild( f, 'H' );
    f->addChild( f, 'I' );
    f->addChild( f, 'J' );
    root = nullptr;
    return 0;
}
```